# Concat function requires two arguments is the coming when i paste the code in ssis

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Concat function requires two arguments is the error generated when i paste the code in ssis. But when i run the query in SQL Management studio i am able to  fetch the results

Comment: Please add both your code and the entire, exact error to your question (do not post them as a comment, edit your question instead)

Comment: Which component in SSIS do you use? Are you sure it's connected to the same DB instance?

Answer (score 1):

The CONCAT function does require 2, or more strings to work. You likely have a query in SSIS that looks like

```
SELECT CONCAT('ABC', @[User::MyVariable) AS MyConcatColumn;
```

That's a common misunderstanding for how SSIS works. If the concatenation work is to be done in TSQL, then you need to parameterize your query - which is dependent upon the database connectivity provider (ODBC vs OLE vs ADO).

Assuming OLEDB, you'd revise the above to

```
DECLARE @TSQLVariable nvarchar(4000) = ?;
SELECT CONCAT('ABC', @TSQLVARIABLE) AS MyConcatColumn;
```

and then click the Parameters button/tab (depends on the component) and map the SSIS variable @[User::MyVariable] into ordinal position 0.